# Spinner при выпадении

Tags: android

Как сделать чтобы при выпадении списка спиннера список всегда начинался бы с начала, не зависимо от того какой итем выбран ранее ?

Answer (score 2):

По умолчанию выводится первый элемент списка. С помощью метода setSelection() можно установить нужный элемент по умолчанию, указав индекс из строкового ресурса.

```
spinner.setSelection(2); //например
```

[источник](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/spinner.php#select)

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы при выпадении списка он начинался всегда с первого элемента, если сделать как Вы написали, то начнется с третьего. Я забыл написать, что список не влезает на весь экран, т.е. при выборе элемента в конце и последующем выборе он скролится на него

Comment: @user225253 `spinner.setSelection(0);`